# I want to Post facebook fan page from my python script

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I want to post news in my facebook fan page from python script .

I am using facebook Open graph test tool to post message in my wall 
but there is error message like this .

(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "Get Access Token" and select "manage_pages" and "publish_actions" to authorize yourself with the apropriate permissions. This will only work for your App if you are trying as user with a role in the App (admin, developer, tester). For other users, you would need to go through the review process of Facebook.

Keep in mind that you will post "as user" in that case. If you want to post "as page", you would need to generate a Page Access Token. Here are some informational links and tutorials about the different Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/